# select2 search on two properties

Tags: javascript, search, jquery-select2

I'm want to add a text property in my select2 data items and be able to search it.

For example I have this data :

```
var data : 
[
    { id : 1, text : 'Item 1', description : 'Long text description for item 1' },
    { id : 2, text : 'Item 2', description : 'Long text description for item 2' },
    { id : 3, text : 'Item 3', description : 'Long text description for item 3' },
]
```

I want select2 to be able to find result if I type text that matches the description property value in the input.

Is it possible to do it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Select2 works with a valid html markup for the underlying select. Where are you going to store the text information since a select has only value and description?

Comment: I don't know, maybe in a `data-description` attribut

Comment: then you have to write your own version of the plugin too. a version that will set the data-* attribute in the select2 markup from the html vesion of the select and a custom search option. this feature is not currently supported. I saw a good answer for a basic search option for a standard select but it got deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create a custom matcher and use it like this

```
$('.select2-typeahead').select2
({
    data : 
    [
        { id : 1, text : 'Item 1', description : 'Long text description for item 1' },
        { id : 2, text : 'Item 2', description : 'Long text description for item 2' },
        { id : 3, text : 'Item 3', description : 'Long text description for item 3' },
    ],
    matcher : function(params, data, item)
    {
        if ($.trim(params) === '') 
        {
            return data;
        }

        if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf(params.toLowerCase()) > -1 || item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(params.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        {
            return data;
        }

        return null;
    }
```